# exporting multiple items to excel using openxml

Tags: asp.net, openxml, export-to-excel

hello all i am working on a project in which i have a webpage wherein i have some textboxes and a button.The functionality of that button is to export the data entered into the textboxes to excel in the form of a table.Also an image(stored on my local drive)needs to be exported too along with the textbox data.All of this i want to achieve through openxml only.This is what i want to achieve.Note that the image which is to be exported is some random image on my local drive.![`input`][1]![output][2]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Thank you

Input
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3vsT.jpg

required output
     [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkILb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the exact sample you can use to display header, cell values and Image in your ASP.NET application using C#:

http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/11/10/how-to-insert-multiple-images-in-excel-open-xml/

If you met any problem, write back here and we sure can help.

Comment: hi avkash thanks for your response...but the site which you mentioned is blocked in my organization :( can you provide me the sample code instead...Thanx once again

Comment: The code is very detailed so I can put together in a sample application and provide a link to you for download however it will take a day to put together. I will send you the sample link by tomorrow if that Ok with you.

Comment: Here is the URL which saved the formatted text/numbers and image on an Excel file. http://happybuddha.blob.core.windows.net/mypublic/CreateExcelOpen.zip (Just edit the code to correct image file name and the excel location where you can save your file)